# How to register HTML text with DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I get following text from the as a result of a AJAX request.

```
<div class="selectMe" >
    <select name="clientAcc" id="clientAcc" style="width: 144px;" >
         <option>JOHN</option>
         <option selected="selected">BOB</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

what i want to do is register this node in HTML DOM and access the select component as
document.getElementById("clientAcc"). I dont know how to do this? can some one please help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q35P8/)

```
var data = <div class="selectMe"> //... plug your ajax response here,
    myDiv  = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.id = 'divClientAcc';
myDiv.innerHTML = data;
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Do note that you cannot have two elements with the same id (clientAcc). You'll have to change/drop the id of the inner select or the appended div.